# Unable to load a custom controller

Tags: ros-lunar, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a custom controller for my omni wheel drive and listed it in my yaml file. But when I tried to launch, Im getting the following error. Tried searching the forum but unable to find an answer that works.

```
[ERROR] [1528923166.098299551]: Could not load class omni_drive/OmniDrive: Failed to load library /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libomni_drive.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libomni_drive.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10omni_drive9OmniDrive8startingERKN3ros4TimeE)
[ERROR] [1528923166.098353074]: Could not load controller 'omni_drive' because controller type 'omni_drive/OmniDrive' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1528923166.098364745]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
[ERROR] [1528923167.100094]: Failed to load omni_drive
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294055/unable-to-load-a-custom-controller/) by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2018-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

forgot to add the class reference in the front of start and stop methods. Use `c++filt -n _ZN10omni_drive9OmniDrive8startingERKN3ros4TimeE`. That solved the problem for me.

---

Originally posted by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) with karma: 89 on 2018-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0